# Как сгладить Polyline в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть в WPF область `Grid`, где я задаю множество точек в `PointCollection` и добавляю это в `Polyline`. Получаю, соответственно, ломаную кривую. Как можно её сгладить на графике? Там всего точек 13 где-то. Слышал про `Bezier`, но там всего 3 точки.
Код простой, в цикле добавляем Point

```
PointsH.Add(new Point(xValueH * j + xValueH / 2, centerYH - onePipsH * (Values[j].Item2 / allProfitsCount) * coeff));
```

И далее присваиваем

```
Polyline polyH = new Polyline()
                {
                    Points = PointsH,
                    Stroke = Brushes.White,
                    StrokeThickness = 1,
                };
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возьмите больше точек

Comment: @АндрейNOP К сожалению, я не могу разбить данные на большие отрезки, поэтому только вот 10 отрезков будет где-то, поэтому нужно как-то сгладить просто углы.

Comment: Это не просто. Если нет возможности получить больше точек изначально, то придется получить их с помощью интерполяции

Comment: @АндрейNOP Понял вас, ладно, буду пытаться как-то получить больше точек, спасибо за совет